# Not able to read characteristic value sent from one BLE Device to Other

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am working on Android Application that sends a String to suppose "Hello World" through BLE. When I scan from other BLE Scanner I got the Service and Characteristic name on the Scanner app but not able to read the actual value of Characteristic that is "Hello World".

Here are snippets of code:-
UUID

```
public static final String UUID_SENSOR_SERVICE = "0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static final String UUID_SENSORS_LEVEL = "00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
```

Creating BluetoothGattService

```
private BluetoothGattService createService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createService: ");
        BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(UUID.fromString(SimpleGattAtributes.UUID_SENSOR_SERVICE), SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

        // Counter characteristic (read-only, supports subscriptions)
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic data = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(SimpleGattAtributes.UUID_SENSORS_LEVEL), PROPERTY_READ , PERMISSION_READ);
        service.addCharacteristic(data);
        return service;
    }
```

Starting GattServer

```
private void startGattServer(Context mContext){
        Log.d(TAG, "startGattServer: ");

        BluetoothGattServerCallback mGattServerCallback =   new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, int offset, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                if (SimpleGattAtributes.UUID_SENSORS_LEVEL.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicReadRequest: I am here");
                    byte[] value = "HelloWorld".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                   
                    mGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0, value);
                }
            }
        };


        mGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(mContext, mGattServerCallback);
        mGattServer.addService(createService());


    }
```

After running the above code, when I open Scanner app, I got my application broadcasting BLE beacons. But When I try to read my characteristic value that is "Hellow World". I did not get it.

Testing on Android Phones

[image]

Trying to read the characteristic value

[image]

Can Anyone help me in that? I use logs and what I see is that **BluetoothGattServerCallback** is not triggering when I click on Read button. It must be triggered.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `onCharacteristicReadRequest` need you try to do the read, do you hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Yes I hit the break point @davidyoung

Comment: @davidgyoung I have set more breakpoints and it comes to me that the if condition is not running (condition evaluating to false)

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks to @davidgyoung

Using breakpoints I found that **If condition** in **BluetoothGattServerCallback** is evaluating to **false** always.

What I am doing wrong in if condition is I am comparing **UUID** with a **String**, that always evaluates to false.

I have to compare a **UUID** with a **UUID**.

Corrected if condition

```
if(UUID.fromString(SimpleGattAtributes.UUID_SENSORS_LEVEL).equals(characteristic.getUuid())){
    // read logic here
}
```

I have checked and it works perfectly.